# Implement Graylog in Magento 2.3 with GelfHandler

Tags: magento2, log

My Magento 2.3 installation came along with a `GelfHandler.php` class that sends messages to a **Graylog2**. 
The `GelfHandler` class looks like:

```
<?php

/*
* This file is part of the Monolog package.
*
* (c) Jordi Boggiano <j.boggiano@seld.be>
*
* For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
* file that was distributed with this source code.
*/

namespace Monolog\Handler;

use Gelf\IMessagePublisher;
use Gelf\PublisherInterface;
use Gelf\Publisher;
use InvalidArgumentException;
use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Formatter\GelfMessageFormatter;

/**
* Handler to send messages to a Graylog2 (http://www.graylog2.org) 
server
*
* @author Matt Lehner <mlehner@gmail.com>
* @author Benjamin Zikarsky <benjamin@zikarsky.de>
*/
class GelfHandler extends AbstractProcessingHandler
{
/**
 * @var Publisher the publisher object that sends the message to the server
 */
protected $publisher;

/**
 * @param PublisherInterface|IMessagePublisher|Publisher $publisher a publisher object
 * @param int                                            $level     The minimum logging level at which this handler will be triggered
 * @param bool                                           $bubble    Whether the messages that are handled can bubble up the stack or not
 */
public function __construct($publisher, $level = Logger::DEBUG, $bubble = true)
{
    parent::__construct($level, $bubble);

    if (!$publisher instanceof Publisher && !$publisher instanceof IMessagePublisher && !$publisher instanceof PublisherInterface) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('Invalid publisher, expected a Gelf\Publisher, Gelf\IMessagePublisher or Gelf\PublisherInterface instance');
    }

    $this->publisher = $publisher;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
protected function write(array $record)
{
    $this->publisher->publish($record['formatted']);
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
protected function getDefaultFormatter()
{
    return new GelfMessageFormatter();
}
}
```

I need guidance how to implement this into my project. Thank you.

Comment: I built a magento 2 module: https://packagist.org/packages/hidro/module-graylog